# Textbelt SMS API - Impossible to send SMS

Tags: php, api, sms

I would like to send SMS thank to the "Textbelt" API (more informations on https://github.com/typpo/textbelt and http://textbelt.com/ ). I tried several methods (php, browser extension, jquery etc...) but I got each time a bug and it displayed "null" variables or error messages (with some "echo" and "var_dump" for testing). Just one solution seems to work, but no SMS is sent. Indeed, when I start this script, I get in a red board "{ "success": true }" but no SMS is sent. Have you some ideas in order to fix it please ? Did I make a mistake ?

Here is the code of this short script :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script>

$(function(){
  var g=  $.post("http://textbelt.com/intl",
  {
    number: "0033xxxxxxxxx",
    message: "testing https://github.com/typpo/textbelt"
  }
  ).done(function (){
    $('#output1').html(g.responseText); 
  });
} 

);

    </script>
    <style>
        #output2 {
                border: 2px solid green;
        }
  #output1 {
                border: 2px solid red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="output1"></div>
<div id="output2"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about other causes, but from your script, I notice that your phone number starts with "0033...". My understanding is that, for phones outside the USA, the number formatting has to be standard (+336...).

The script behind TextBelt does a brute-force sequential sending of the message to the e-mail gateways of all known carriers in the country by using the phone number you submitted, then formatting it for each specific individual carrier's gateway (ex: 337xxxxxxxx@orange.fr) and trying to send it to that carrier, then going to the next, until it sends to all. Eventually, it will succeed with one of them and the message will be delivered properly.

A plain vanilla HTML form like this one works (I tested it):

```
<form action=http://textbelt.com/intl method="post" name=TextMessage>
<p>
Number: <input type=text name=number>
</p>
<p>
Message: <input type=text name=message>
</p>
<p>
<input type=Submit name=Submit value=Submit>
</form>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: At first, thank you for your help ! Don't worry, it helps me alot ;) .

Comment: However, I made a html script with this source code and I filled it with a number like "+337XXXXXXXX" and my message too but it doesn't work. It displays "{ "success": true }"  but I can't receive the SMS. I tried on 2 different phones but it was the same result. Textbelt works in France only with phone with the "Orange" provider/carrier please ?

Comment: Up ! (Predrag Vasić, thank you for your help at first, but if you have no ideas, can you say it please so that I try other forums or peoples?)

Comment: Besides, what was your phone carrier ? Or at least, the carrier of the phone you sent a SMS please ?

Comment: I know this answers comes way too late, but in case anyone is looking; I don't know why the script didn't work for you. My carrier is in the USA (T-Mobile USA).

Possible reason why the script didn't work may be that its list of carrier email-to-text gateways isn't accurate, and your particular carrier isn't listed, or is listed with the wrong gateway. On their website (textbelt.com), they list all supported carriers. If you can't find yours, the script won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The repo contains a bootstrap for a module setup or a  standalone server. For the code above appears to be a client request that should be directed toward your self-hosted texbelt-clone-server and not the one served at textbelt.com. You should use ngrok or jprq to expose your texbelt-clone-server for accessing over WAN.
the form action should therefore, be as follows

```
...action=http://url-from_ngrok_service_port.com/file_sms_send_hanlder.php?id=intl" method="post"...
```